# How can I create a tree data structure from a YAML file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, yaml

Suppose I have a YAML file as follows:

```
template:
 artifacts:
  config:
   a: value1
   b: value2
  jars:
   a: value1
   b: value2
  scripts:
   a: value1
   b: value2
```

I would like to have it like a tree as below:

```
template--
          |__artifacts__
                        |__config__
                        |          |__a__
                        |          |     |__value1
                        |          |
                        |          |__b__
                        |                |__value2
                        |__jars__ ...
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple parsers for YAML available for Python, but the only
one supporting the latest YAML specification (1.2, released in 2009)
is [ruamel.yaml](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (disclaimer:
I am the author of that package). The other packages (PySyck, PyYAML)
also do not support loading of valid YAML constructs such as
sequences/mappings as mapping keys. `ruamel.yaml` can be directed to
dump YAML 1.1 for those outdated packages that only support that
version of the YAML specification.

Nested python `dict`s can be used as a tree structure, with the keys a
value of a node and the values that are non-`dict`s leaf nodes. This is the
datastructure that is loaded from the mappings in your YAML file.

```
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint
import ruamel.yaml

input = Path('input.yaml')
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(input)
pprint(data)
```

which gives:

```
{'template': {'artifacts': {'config': {'a': 'value1',
                                       'b': 'value2'},
                            'jars': {'a': 'value1',
                                     'b': 'value2'},
                            'scripts': {'a': 'value1',
                                        'b': 'value2'}}}}
```

This doesn't look like your expected output, nor are dicts really a tree structure.
You can of course walk over your `data`-structure and create a tree of `Node`s, but
that is a bit backward, as you can tell the parser to directly create a `Node`
when building the tree.

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml.constructor import SafeConstructor

class Node:
    # your node definition here
    pass


class MyConstructor(SafeConstructor):
    def construct_yaml_map(self, node):
        data = Node()
        yield data
        res = self.construct_mapping(node)
        # and update data with the parsed data

MyConstructor.add_constructor('tag:yaml.org,2002:map', 
                              MyConstructor.construct_yaml_map)


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.Constructor = MyConstructor
data = yaml.load(input)
```

Please note that the above automatically deals with recursive structures in your YAML file,
something not as easily realised when walking over the YAML loaded in the normal way.