# generate text tree for a non-existant folder structure

Tags: tree, filesystems, utility-method

I want to generate a beautiful text rendering of a file system / folder structure that *does not exist*. Imagine I want to propose a file system layout, I would like to express this in an easy way I can quickly type down. For instance, given an input like this:

```
another
    folder
    log.txt
final
hi.py
some
    folder
        file.txt
```

where hierarchy is simply expressed by Tabs. Could be any other encoding though.

I would like to get a beatiful output like [`tree`](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/) could generate:

```
.
├── another
│   ├── folder
│   └── log.txt
├── final
├── hi.py
└── some
    └── folder
        └── file.txt
```

The goal here is to avoid typing non-type-able but beautiful characters like `└──` or `├──`. Ideally, a web-version of this tool would be desirable.

There are a bunch of seemingly related SO posts: [What tool to use to draw file tree diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347551/what-tool-to-use-to-draw-file-tree-diagram) or [Representing Directory & File Structure in Markdown Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699059/representing-directory-file-structure-in-markdown-syntax). However, all of them need an existing folder structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What tool to use to draw file tree diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347551/what-tool-to-use-to-draw-file-tree-diagram)

Comment: Your question is probably more relevant to (Software Recommendations)[https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/]

Comment: Thanks @dank8, but no. The `tree` alternative is already described in my question, but I want to avoid creating actual files and folders. Graphviz seems more work than actually creating files and folders.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is the tool you want: [tree.nathanfriend.io](https://tree.nathanfriend.io) . It is a simple two pane website.  On the left you enter exactly what you showed as sample input (with tabs). On the right it shows you exactly what you requested as output.
[image: Example with your sample input]

Answer (score 1):

What you have expressed as input is very close to [YAML](https://yaml.org/) structure.

I'm unable to determine where you want to use the beautified result.

are you a developer bulk document generation:

- [templating tools (python.org)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating)
- I recently found [jinja2 (pypi)](https://pypi.org/project/Jinja2/)
- [ruamel.yaml (previous answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53143122/6345724)

are you a technical or business writer giving a presentation:

- web search for YAML beautifier
- [google result included codebeautify.org](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-viewer-online)

Comment: thanks! I like the YAML idea. Even though the proposed rendering of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53143122/3702319) isn't as compact (and hence beautiful) as I'd wish. Maybe I will write a quick `yaml-tree` tool that mimics the output format of `tree` but parses yaml files.